# Import and clear a MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, import

I'm connecting to a remote MongoDB server, importing all of the items from it into a local database, and then clearing it.

Is there a safer and more efficient way to do this?

```
mongoexport -h 1.2.3.4 -d foo -c bar | mongoimport -d foo -c bar
mongo 1.2.3.4/foo --eval "db.bar.remove()"
mongo 1.2.3.4/foo --eval "db.repairDatabase()"  # To free up disk space
```

The remote database is much smaller than the one that I'm importing into, so replication doesn't seem like an option.

Comment: Just to clarify, your remote database is very small, so you're using it to capture data for some amount of time, then moving that data to your local server, which has more disk space?  Is that correct?  Also, what is the nature of your application?

Comment: @sfritter: Yep. It's an Amazon EC2 server with 8GB of disk space that I use for aggregating data.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about your use case?  What's being done with the data after it's moved, for example, and what sort of application interacts with the Amazon instance.  There are more efficient ways to accomplish what you're doing, but the more I know about your use case, the better I can advise you :)

Comment: @sfritter: It's just data that I'm aggregating over a two or three year period of time through a web crawler. The size of the data grows about 500GB a year, which is far too expensive to store "in the cloud", which is why I download it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose I would first switch from using mongoexport/mongoimport to using [mongodump/mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-binary-database-dumps/). Mongodump is faster, and also will preserve all rich BSON data types, unlike mongoexport.

Also, the command `db.bar.remove()` will go through your collection document by document and drop each one. Since you really want to just get rid of everything, you can do this much more quickly by [dropping the entire collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) wholesale with `db.bar.drop()`. This is much faster. However, dropping the collection will also drop any indexes you have built for it, so you will need to recreate those afterwards.

It shouldn't be necessary for you to run db.repairDatabase() after each migration, because MongoDB will reclaim the freed space from dropping your collection. What you can do is to use `compact` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/) to defragment the freed space. Additionally, you can try using the `usePowerOf2Sizes` flag for this collection, which should help MongoDB reuse space more efficiently (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/).

Replication is not what you're looking for. With replication, we run several servers that all contain copies of the same data, not subsets of a dataset. This is mainly useful for disaster recovery and failover, and wouldn't help in your case.

Comment: Does `mongodump`/`mongorestore` merge databases, or does it replace them?

Comment: Unless you use the `--drop` option, mongorestore will merge your data.